# Add external html and css file in a servlets project created in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I have a servlets project called LoginPortal. In this project, I intend to add an html called `login.html` and a css file called `login.css` . I added them to `Webcontent` folder which is where I added other html files that I created in project it self.
Besides `login.html` and `login.css`, all other files were created n the project only and so work just fine.

The directory structure now looks like this:

[image]

However , I still get `404` error when I try to access this html file added externally :

[image]

URL :`http://localhost:8080/LoginPortal/login.html`

What could be the possible reasons ?

Comment: Your screenshot contradicts your description: it shows login.html out of WEB-INF (which is a good thing: everything inside WEB-INF can't be accessed from the outside).

Comment: @JB NIzet: I am sorry, I meant web content folder only.When i create the html and css in eclipse, it works ,however ,adding them from outside directly in the same location does not. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: Have you redeployed the app?

Comment: are you adding files directly to the workspace/project folder instead of through eclipse??

Comment: @JafarAli: Yes, that is exactly what I did. Is there a problem in doing that ?

Comment: yes. Eclipse seems to maintain a list of files which it will deploy to target server when invoked. Since you added this externally and eclipse does not know, it will not deploy this files.

Comment: Okay, That helped . But what I do not understand is what kind of files it may need to maintain for static HTML files added externally to project ? It would be great f you could throw some light on same. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse seems to maintain a list of files which it will be deploy to target server when changed.

Since, you added those files externally and eclipse does not know about them yet, it will not deploy this files when changed. 
You can do this. after adding this files externally go to eclipse project explorer. Refresh your project from your context menu(Right click -> refresh). This will include the file you added and get listed.

The files will be added instantly when ever there is a changes, and is reflected in the output.

Comment: The project indeed was refreshed and files were visible in eclipse project explorer.

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Glassfish